# Start transaction in one action class and commit it on another in struts 2

Tags: hibernate

I am writting a code in an action class to insert a record in database but not commit it at the same time as I want to commit it later after some other record has been inserted using a different action class. I am new to hibernate and don't know how to do this. Please, guide me. I am using struts 2.Thanks in advance.
I am using the following code in an Action to insert a record in database without commiting

```
    public void addExamDetails( ExamDetails examDetails){
       try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(examDetails);
       } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamDetailsDAO.addExamDetails()");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

After this, in another action class I am writting the following code to insert other record and commiting at the same time but I am not able to commit the previous insertion

```
public void addExamShift( ExamShift examShift){
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            session.save(examShift);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamShiftDAO.addExamShift()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Ok, I am posting those two actions. Please guide me.
This is the first action where exam details are inserted, but commit doesn't take place.

```
package com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement.hibernate.ExamDetails;
import com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement.hibernate.ExamDetailsDAO;

public class AddExamDetailsAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<ExamDetails> {

    private ExamDetails examDetails = new ExamDetails();
    private ExamDetailsDAO examDetailsDAO = new ExamDetailsDAO();

    private int examCode;

    public ExamDetails getModel(){
        return examDetails;
    }

    public String execute(){
        String result = ERROR;
        try{
            examDetailsDAO.addExamDetails(examDetails);
            result = SUCCESS;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("AddExamDetailsAction.execute()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int getExamCode(){
        return examCode;
    }

    public void validate(){
        if(examDetails.getExamName().trim().equals("") ){
            addFieldError("examName", "Exam Name is required");
        }
        if(examDetails.getAcademicSession().equals("-1")){
            addFieldError("academicSession", "Session is Required");
        }

    }

}
```

After this the following action is called to insert shift details of the exam. And it is where the commit of both transaction takes place.

```
package com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement.hibernate.ExamShift;
import com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement.hibernate.ExamShiftDAO;

public class AddShiftDetailsAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<ExamShift> {

    private ExamShift examShift = new ExamShift();

    private ExamShiftDAO examShiftDAO = new ExamShiftDAO();

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;

    private boolean shiftError;
    private boolean startHourError;
    private boolean startMinuteError;
    private boolean startTimeSuffixError;
    private boolean endHourError;
    private boolean endMinuteError;
    private boolean endTimeSuffixError;

    private boolean validationFailed;


    public ExamShift getModel(){
        return examShift;
    }

    public String execute(){
        String result = ERROR;
        try{

            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            examShiftDAO.addExamShift(examShift);
            result = SUCCESS;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("AddShiftDetailsAction.execute()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean getShiftError(){
        return shiftError;
    }
    public boolean getStartHourError(){
        return startHourError;
    }
    public boolean getStartMinuteError(){
        return startMinuteError;
    }
    public boolean getStartTimeSuffixError(){
        return startTimeSuffixError;
    }
    public boolean getEndHourError(){
        return endHourError;
    }
    public boolean getEndMinuteError(){
        return endMinuteError;
    }
    public boolean getEndTimeSuffixError(){
        return endTimeSuffixError;
    }
    public boolean getValidationFailed(){
        return validationFailed;
    }

    public void validate(){
        try{
            if(examShift.getShift() == 0 ){
                shiftError = true;
                validationFailed = true;
                addFieldError("shift", "Exam Shift is required");
                System.out.println("Action : shift");
            }
            if(examShift.getStartHour() == -1){
                startHourError = true;
                validationFailed = true;
                addFieldError("startHour", "Start Time is Required");
                System.out.println("Action : startHour");
            }
            if(examShift.getStartMinute() == -1){
                startMinuteError = true;
                validationFailed = true;
                addFieldError("startMinute", "Start Time is Required");
                System.out.println("Action : startMinute");
            }
            if(examShift.getStartTimeSuffix().equals("-1")){
                startTimeSuffixError = true;
                validationFailed = true;
                addFieldError("startTimeSuffix", "Start Time is Required");
                System.out.println("Action : startTimeSuffix");
            }
            if(examShift.getEndHour() == -1){
                endHourError = true;
                validationFailed = true;
                addFieldError("endHour", "End Time is required");
                System.out.println("Action : endHour");
            }
            if(examShift.getEndMinute() == -1){
                endMinuteError = true;
                validationFailed = true;
                addFieldError("endMinute", "End Time is required");
                System.out.println("Action : endMinute");
            }
            if(examShift.getEndTimeSuffix().equals("-1")){
                endTimeSuffixError = true;
                validationFailed = true;
                addFieldError("endTimeSuffix", "End Time is required");
                System.out.println("Action : endTimeSuffix");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("AddShiftDetailsAction.validate()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The later insertion ( Shift Details ) is committed successfully but the previous one ( Exam Details ) is not committed.
   The following are my two DAO to insert those records in the database

```
package com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ExamDetailsDAO {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Session session;
    Transaction transaction;

    public List<ExamDetails> getExamDetails(){
        List<ExamDetails> examDetails = new ArrayList<ExamDetails>();
        try{
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            examDetails = session.createQuery("FROM ExamDetails").list();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamDetailsDAO.getExamDetails()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return examDetails;
    }

    public void addExamDetails( ExamDetails examDetails){
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(examDetails);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamDetailsDAO.addExamDetails()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void editExamDetails( ExamDetails examDetails ){
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamDetailsDAO.editExamDetails()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


package com.zealsofts.schoolmanagement.hibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ExamShiftDAO {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Session session;
    Transaction transaction;

    public List<ExamShift> getExamShifts(){
        List<ExamShift> examShifts = new ArrayList<ExamShift>();
        try{
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            examShifts = session.createQuery("FROM ExamShift").list();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamDetailsDAO.getExamDetails()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return examShifts;
    }

    public void addExamShift( ExamShift examShift){
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            session.save(examShift);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamShiftDAO.addExamShift()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void editExamShift( ExamShift examShift ){
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExamShiftDAO.editExamShift()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: You simply shouldn't do that. What if the second action is never executed? If you have some sort of wizard and the whole thing must be saved at the end, then keep the intermediate state in memory and save everything at the end, or save the intermediate state in specific tables, or with a "draft" status, and read back the state from these tables at the end to save the whole thing in the final tables, in a single transaction.

Comment: Thank you, Well I want to do it like a wizard. In first action I am inserting exam name and in another, shift details of exam. If the second action ( for shift details ) doesn't get executed then the exam details will also not be saved. So I want to do it.

Comment: Have you read my comment? Your first action should simply keep the exam name in memory (in the HTTP session, for example). You could also simply use a hidden field in the second page to hold the exam name, which would make it even cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with you, I could carry the exam details on second page, but I want to keep the code more modularized. I mean exam details should be inserted through 'ExamDetailsDAO' and shift details through my 'ShiftDetailsDAO'. So, I want to do like that.

Comment: What you have posted it's just two methods, if you have actions post actions, without code that execute action, configuration, plug-ing, JSPs, your question would be off-topic.

Comment: Finally I solved the problem, the problem was that I was obtaining new SessionFactory object in every class and hence getting new transaction every time. Thank you for giving your time

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem, the problem was that I was obtaining new SessionFactory object in every class and hence getting new transaction every time. Thank you for giving your time